# Transfering columns between tables that have a relationship

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

table_Names

id, name

11, Harry

12, Wayne

13, Raheem

14, Manuel

15, Thomas

table_relationship

A_id, B_id

11, 14

12, 15

I need all the names for the ids that has the A-B relationships to update.

So, I want table_Names to look like this after the SQL update;

11, Manuel

12, Thomas

13, Raheem

14, Manuel

15, Thomas

How should the mySQL statement look like?

I tried this:

```
UPDATE table_Names
INNER JOIN table_relationship
ON table_Names.id = A.id
SET table_Names=table_Names
WHERE table_relationship.Aid=table_names.id
```

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting, please feel free to improve on that, anyone!

Comment: Please feel free to read about how to edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free coding or code conversion or tutorial or library finding service** You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: @mhawke That link doesn't say anything about how to format tables...?

Comment: Post your query. What ever you have written so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by joining `table_Names` to the relationship table, then joining back again to `table_Names`.

```
UPDATE table_Names AS t1
INNER JOIN table_relationship AS t2
    ON t1.id = t2.A_id
INNER JOIN table_Names t3
    ON t2.B_id = t3.id
SET t1.name = t3.name
```

Note that there is no fear of updating records which do appear in `table_relationship` because these records will filtered off by the `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, could not fully understand this, but double join did the trick!